# How to correct domain in URLs after a change?

Tags: drupal, lts, migration

I installed CiviCRM 4.4 (LTS) on `foo.example.com` and then needed to move it to `bar.example.com`. I have updated the **Resource URLs** page with the new domain. However certain links, for example the links to "View and edit custom fields" on the custom data page at `/civicrm/admin/custom/group` still all point to the old domain.

I've tried `drush cc all; drush -u 1 civicrm-update-cfg` but the links are still the old ones.

Have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe worth a try with Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths?

Comment: Thanks, tried that also but no good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would double check the `civicrm.settings.php` file to make sure the paths and URL are updated in there. For example:

```
define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'http://foo.example.com/' );
```

While you are in there make sure the server paths look right:

```
$civicrm_root = '/home/path_to_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm';
define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', '/home/path_to_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/' );
```

Comment: who-hoo! thanks, that was it! Knew I'd have missed something. Many thanks  for your time.